# Angular - How to pass back value from submit button to call a function?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a html which has the following dropdown list

```
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let t of items" value="t">
          {{ t }}
        </option>
    </select>
```

Now I also have a submit button on the same page

```
<button type="button" (click)="selectedValue()" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
  Submit
</button>
```

What I would like to do is to take the value user has selected. I am assuming it is stored in "t" and then pass it in a function

```
 selectedValue() {
    // would like to call 
updateValue(t) { }
    
    
      }
```

Something like that.. Not sure where to being from the html back to the ts and then calling a function which will update value and give a 200ok result from http call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with `ngModel` with two-way binding.

While for the option either use `[value]` directive or `value="{{ t }}"`. As currently, each option is holding the value with "t" string which is incorrect.

```
<select [(ngModel)]='selectedOption'>
  <option *ngFor="let t of items" [value]="t">
      {{ t }}
    </option>
</select>
```

```js
selectedOption: string;

selectedValue() {
  this.updateValue(this.selectedOption);
}

updateValue(t) { 
  console.log(t);
}
```

[Sample StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-semmpo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)